# Instalar PagSeguro/PHP no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

No `composer.php` estou colocando assim:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "pagseguro/php": "dev-master", #"pagseguro/php": "2.5.0",
    "cagartner/correios-consulta": "0.1.*",
    "intervention/image": "2.*"
},
```

Mas está dando erro:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> **Problem 1**
>      - The requested package pagseguro/php could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
>
> **Potential causes:**
>   - A typo in the package name
>   - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
>     see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion >for more details.
>
> Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

Mas o diretório existe no **GitHub**.
https://github.com/pagseguro/php

Resolvido!

A versão **2.5.0** não é um diretório no GitHub. Depois pesquisando encontrei que deveria ser **"pagseguro/php":"dev-master"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A biblioteca que voce esta tentando utilizar não é propria para laravel.

Abra o arquivo composer.json e insira a seguinte instrução:

```
"require": {
    "michael/laravelpagseguro": "dev-master"
}
```

Após inserir no require o Laravel PagSeguro, você deverá executar o comando:

```
composer update
```

Fonte para mais informações: [PagSeguro Laravel](https://github.com/michaeldouglas/laravel-pagseguro)

Comment: Otto, mas esse PagSeguro é o Checkout Transparente ?

Comment: Sim você envia a requisição sem sair da sua aplicação

Comment: Certo. Vou ter que criar outro tópico para uma dúvida minha. Obrigado.